# Slow PySpark script with very low volume

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

It takes about 40 minutes on a 8core/32G Windows computer to run following Python script. Why is it so slow?

```
for he in range(1, 25):
    he_str = str(he)
    ### df_all is a dataframe that contains only 3200 records ###
    ### df_all does contain 146 columns. Maybe this is why? ###
    df_all = df_all.withColumn('PROFIT_INC_HE' + he_str, functions.lit(0))
    df_all = df_all.withColumn('PROFIT_DEC_HE' + he_str, functions.lit(0))

    ### TIER_PRICE_FACTORS is list of 4 elements ###
    for tiers in TIER_PRICE_FACTORS:
        tiers_str = str(tiers).replace('.', '')

        df_all = df_all.withColumn('PROFIT_INC_HE' + he_str, functions.col('PROFIT_INC_HE' + he_str) \
                                    + functions.col('BID_PROFIT_INC_HE' + he_str + '_' + tiers_str))

        df_all = df_all.withColumn('PROFIT_DEC_HE' + he_str, functions.col('PROFIT_DEC_HE' + he_str) \
                                    + functions.col('BID_PROFIT_Dec_HE' + he_str + '_' + tiers_str))
```